# Lightning Error in Chrome browser, safari and firefox working fine

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

The below code is working fine in safari and firefox browser however in chrome I am getting the following errors. Can anyone shed some light.

[image]
[image]

component code:

```
<aura:component controller="QueryLimitAuraClient">

<!-- Non functional - check box for toggling between number and percentage-->
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="showPercent" label="Percentage?" click="{!c.showPercentCtrl}"/>
<!-- call  controller when this component is initialized-->
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.getQueryLimitCtrl}" value="{!this}" />
<!-- define the attribute variable -->
<aura:attribute name="querylimitnumber" type="Integer" />
<!-- helper method will populate the variable  after receiving response from aura enabled server-->
<ui:outputText value="{!v.querylimitnumber}" />

</aura:component>
```

controller code:

```
getQueryLimitCtrl : function(component, event, helper) {
  console.log('>>>>> getQueryLimitCtrl - START');
  helper.getQueryLimitUsedNumberHelper(component);
  console.log('>>>>> getQueryLimitCtrl - END');
}
```

helper code:

```
getQueryLimitUsedNumberHelper : function(component, queryUsed) {

console.log('>>>>> getQueryLimitUsedNumberHelper: START');
var action = component.get('c.getQueryLimitNumber');

action.setCallback(this, function(response){

  if(response.getState() === "SUCCESS"){
    console.log('>>>>> SUCCESS: Async response from Helper : ' + response.getReturnValue());
    component.set("v.querylimitnumber", response.getReturnValue());
  }else if(response.getState() === "ERROR"){
    console.log('>>>>> ERROR : Async response from Helper : ' + response.getError());
    $A.log(response.getError() );
  }
});

$A.enqueueAction(action);

console.log('>>>>> getQueryLimitUsedNumberHelper: END');
}
```

Apex Code:

```
public with sharing class QueryLimitAuraClient {
private static Map<String, Object> errorMap ;
private static Integer QUERY = 0;
private static final string QUERY_KEY = 'QUERY';
@AuraEnabled
public static integer getQueryLimitNumber() {

LimitStrategy queryLimitStrategy = new LimitNumberImpl();
queryLimitStrategy.solveGovernorLimit();
errorMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped( queryLimitStrategy.getMessages() );
QUERY = Integer.valueOf(errorMap.get( QUERY_KEY ) );
return QUERY;

}
}
```

Comment: Nothing looks even remotely browser specific here and you are using the latest version of Chrome (54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)) - scratching my head on this one. For completeness could you also include the code for the Apex controller?

Comment: ... I took an educated guess and stubbed out an Apex controller as public class QueryLimitAuraClient {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Integer getQueryLimitNumber() {
        return 1234;
    }
} and I am seeing no issues on any browser I have tried thus far including Chrome.

Comment: Doug I added the Apex code for your reference, one pointer I would like to mention is that if I remove $A.enqueueAction(action) then I do not see the error, of course I do not see any data either.

Comment: @ArupSarkar try testing that on a different computer with chrome, maybe the problem is specifically for this chrome, maybe some chrome extension is interfering

Comment: After removing the Lightning Inspector from Chrome DevTools I am not getting the error in Chrome anymore, I will re enable it and see, will update the post after few rounds of testing.